# TestCase self.assertEqual does not match a similar string

Tags: python, django-testing, django-unittest, django-tests

I'am trying to create a model unittest for a ManyToMany relationship.
The aim is to check, if there is the right category saved in the table Ingredient.

```
class IngredientModelTest(TestCase):
    def test_db_saves_ingredient_with_category(self):
        category_one = IngredientsCategory.objects.create(name='Food')
        first_Ingredient = Ingredient.objects.create(name='Apple')
        first_Ingredient.categories.add(category_one)

        category_two = IngredientsCategory.objects.create(name='Medicine')
        second_Ingredient = Ingredient.objects.create(name='Antibiotics')
        second_Ingredient.categories.add(category_two)

        first_ = Ingredient.objects.first()
        self.assertEqual('Apple', first_.name)
        self.assertEqual(first_.categories.all(), [category_one])
        self.assertEqual(first_, first_Ingredient)
```

for `self.asserEqual(first_.categories.all(), [category_one])` in the second last row I get this weird assert:

```
AssertionError: [<IngredientsCategory: Food>] != [<IngredientsCategory: Food>]
```

I tried many other different ways, but none of it worked. Does any one suppose how I can get the information of `first_.categories.all()` to compare it with something else?

Comment: It is most probably because of types are not matching. all() returns queryset and you're comparing it with a list. Have you check it?

Comment: Try `self.assertEqual(first_.categories.get(), category_one)` if you want to test that there's only one result there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That'll be because they're not equal - one is a `QuerySet`, the other is a `list` - they just happen to have the same `str` representations.

You could either cast the `QuerySet` to a list with `list(first_.categories.all())`, or a possible solution for this situation may be:

```
self.assertEqual(first_.categories.get(), category_one)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. And this is for those who come along with the same problem and wants to compare more then one `QuerySet` value. At least I figured out how it will work in my case:                                `self.assertEqual([value for value in last_.categories.all()], [category_one, category_two,])`

Comment: No worries. You can just do `list(last_.categories.all())` instead of using the list comprehension if you prefer.

Comment: Nice. Yes that looks much better